# Android Location deprecated?

Tags: android, api, location

I noticed that Android Location seems to be deprecated. I found in the API reference (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html) this: This API is not the recommended method for accessing Android location.

It is quite confusing because there is not information about this in the API of the class Location. And it still works well.

I guess there are some good reasons to stop using the Location class. I would like to know which is the recommended way to locate a user and implement a location-based application. Do I have to change my app to the new way that is linked? I am a little bit disappointed that this remark is only on one page.

Comment: As the older API has got some performance issue like battery drainage problem. So, Google recommends us to use https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html. And they are not giving further support or adding up new features to the deprecated API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes android LocationApi is deprecated.

FusedLocationProviderApi is also deprecated 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi

Now you should migrate to the new FusedLocationProviderClient -- 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily true that `android.location` isn't supported any longer, since it has actually had some API changes as of Android Oreo (look at the [`Location`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class). It's just a "low-level" API for location that is common across all Android devices, but doesn't offer the benefit of power-savings and accuracy that Google's Fused Location Provider does. Underneath it all, Fused Location Provider utilizes `android.location`, just in an efficient manner.

Unless you really have a need for the granularity of control over location calls and are able to properly manage the power consumption of the calls you make for it, it's recommended to use Fused Location Provider.